# Why does this dynamic Nginx proxy configuration not work?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a nginx configuration that looks like this:

```
location /textproxy {
  proxy_pass http://$arg_url;
  proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
  proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
  add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

The idea is that this proxies to a remote url, and rewrites the content header to be text/plain.

For example I would call:

```
http://nx/textproxy?url=http://foo:50070/a/b/c?arg=abc:123
```

And it would return the contents of `http://foo:50070/a/b/c?arg=abc:123`, but wrapped with a text/plain header.

This doesn't seem to work though, I constantly get 'invalid upstream port' errors:

```
2013/07/23 19:05:10 [error] 25292#0: *963177 invalid port in upstream "http://foo:50070/a/b/c?arg=abc:123", client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: ~^(?<h>nx)(\..+|)$, request: "GET /textproxy?url=http://foo:50070/a/b/c?arg=abc:123 HTTP/1.1", host: "nx"
```

Any ideas? I'm having a hard time trying to work it out.

Comment: does the url work fine when you open it directly on the browser?

Comment: proxy_pass http://$arg_url; + ?url=http://foo:50070/a/b/c?arg=abc:123 http:// is repeated